# why index out of range exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, webforms

I am using this code to get the index of `last row` in gridview and then putting empty string in particular cell but throws error: `Index out of range`

```
protected void grdViewAdvances_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        int RowIndex = grdViewAdvances.Rows.Count-1 ;

        grdViewAdvances.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[5].Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: How many columns do you have in GridView?

Comment: @Adil Guess >= 5 .

Comment: Try giving 3 or 4 in Cells to check if it is due to column or row

Comment: not working on any column

Comment: @Adil 6 but i tried every column

Comment: @tchelidze any solution becuase it has wasted a lot of my time ?

Comment: Why don't you check the *Counts* of *Rows* and *Cells* at the moment when the exception is thrown, and let us know them.

Comment: @Quoran Try `grdViewAdvances.Rows[Math.Min(RowIndex].Cells[grdViewAdvances.Rows[RowIndex].Cells.Count - 1,5)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows count would be changing for each row RowDataBound event. If you want to change the Text of last row column then let the bind process finish and assign the empty string after RowDataBound.

You probably need to do after the `DataBind()` method.

```
grdViewAdvances.DataSource = dt;
grdViewAdvances.DataBind();
grdViewAdvances.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[5].Text = "";
```

**Edit**

I just debugged the code and when on first time the code executed under if statement you have the Row Count is zero and subtracting one from it will give you row = -1 which is surely out of bound index.

Comment: but i still don't get why databound event failed ? it should have given mey the index

Comment: You are welcome, current row is not added in GridView when RowDataBound is actually triggered. I hope you would understand it.